# Error creando Trigger con Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Estoy creando un trigger con PhpMyAdmin para que al realizar una modificación en la "table1" se elimine el elemento de la "table2" al que la "fk_element" sea igual a la "id" del elemento modificado.

Estos son los campos del trigger:

Tabla `table1` tiempo `AFTER` y evento `UPDATE`.
Contenido del trigger:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE fk_element = OLD.id;
INSERT INTO table2 (priority, fulldayevent, location, label, fk_element, elementtype, fk_project, datep, datef, percentage, note)
VALUES (0, 0, '', CONCAT(NEW.ref, ' - ', NEW.label), NEW.id, 'project_task', NEW.fk_project, NEW.date_start, NEW.date_end, NEW.progress, NEW.description)
```

El problema que da error sin especificar el motivo, he probado el `DELETE` y el `INSERT` por separado y funcionan correctamente.
¿Alguien sabe cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución (definición de PhpMyAdmin):

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM llx_actioncomm WHERE fk_element = OLD.id;
    INSERT INTO llx_actioncomm (priority, fulldayevent, location, label, fk_element, elementtype, fk_project, datep, datef, percentage, note)
    VALUES (0, 0, '', CONCAT(NEW.ref, ' - ', NEW.label), NEW.id, 'project_task', NEW.fk_project, NEW.date_start, NEW.date_end, NEW.progress, NEW.description);
END
```

Comment: Será definición en MySQL, pues phpmyadmin es solo una interfaz visual para manipular tus bases de datos

Comment: Sí, aunque me refería a que en PhpMyAdmin, dentro de el "editor" de triggers ese fragmento de código va dónde pone definición.